# índice com pontilhado de largura 100%

Tags: css

No CSS tem como fazer um índice igual o do Word pegando 100% da largura do contêiner e usando pontinhos para separar o "título" do "número da página"?

Tipo:

- Introdução - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  - -  - - - - - - - - - - - - - -20
- Metas - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -20
- Metodologia - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  - -  - - - - - - - - - - - - -20

Comment: Poste o seu `html`, por favor

Comment: Fonte: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746491/how-to-draw-a-dotted-line-with-css`(obs; substitua dotted por dashed) Outra Fonte: `http://www.sovavsiti.cz/css/hr.html`

Comment: Pergunta bem parecida com a sua http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097851/fill-available-spaces-between-labels-with-dots-or-hyphens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problemática disso é semelhante à de players que precisam de espaço para botões, sendo a "linha do tempo" a mesma coisa que os pontinhos. [Flex](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) já possui um bom suporte. Se quiser aprender mais sobre flex, eu recomendo o curso do [Wes Bos](http://flexbox.io/), é totalmente gratuito, mas em inglês :)

```css
.teste {
  max-width:100%;
}
.teste li {
  overflow:hidden;
  display:flex;
}
.teste li span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.teste li div {
}
.teste li div:before {
  content:'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------';
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.teste > a {
  display:flex;
  text-decoration:none;
}


/* extra para demonstração */
main {
  width:100%;
}
main > section {
  width:75%;
  float:left;
}
main > aside {
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  margin-left:5%;
  background:#e7e7e7;
  min-width:100px;
}
```

```html
<main>
<section>
  <h1>Indice</h1>
  <!-- Começa aqui -->
  <ul class="teste">
    <a href="#">
      <li>
        <span>Introdução </span>
        <div></div>
      </li>
      <div>20</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>
        <span>Metas</span>
        <div></div>
      </li>
      <div>20</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>
        <span>Metodologia</span>
        <div></div>
      </li>
      <div>20</div>
    </a>
  </ul>
  <!-- Termina Aqui -->
</section>
<aside>
  <p>blablabla<br>
  blablabla<br>
  blablabla<br>
  blablabla<br>
  blablabla<br>
  blablabla<br>
  blablabla
  </p>
</aside>
</main>
```

Answer (score 5):

Se não tiver texturas ou imagens de fundo, um jeito bem "barato" de fazer é deixar a linha inteira pontilhada, e "tampar" com o fundo dos elementos das pontas (o nome e o número).

A vantagem neste caso é a simplicidade do código:

```css
li span { background: #fff }
li span+span { float: right }
li { position: relative }
li::before {
  content: "";
  display: block; position: absolute; z-index: -1;
  top: 50%; width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Índice</h1>
<ul>
  <li><span>Introdução</span> <span>20</span></li>
  <li><span>Metas</span> <span>20</span></li>
  <li><span>Metodologia</span> <span>20</span></li>
</ul>
```

Basicamente o que acontece aqui é que o fundo dos spans é pintado de branco (obviamente tem que adaptar à cor da página), efetivamente escondendo os traços.

O `z-index` serve para garantir que a linha fique escondida pelo fundo da parte escrita.

### Estilizando um pouco melhor:

Veja mais um exemplo, desta vez dando um espaço extra entre a linha e o fundo, e fazendo com pontilhado:

```css
li span { background: #fff; padding: 0 12px 0 0 }
li span+span { float: right; padding: 0 0 0 12px }
li { position: relative }
li::before {
  content: "";
  display: block; position: absolute; z-index: -1;
  top: 67%; width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #000;
}
```

```html
<h1>Índice</h1>
<ul>
  <li><span>Introdução</span> <span>20</span></li>
  <li><span>Metas</span> <span>20</span></li>
  <li><span>Metodologia</span> <span>20</span></li>
</ul>
```

No caso, usei `2px` no `border-bottom`, e `dotted` (que é o pontilhado) no lugar do `dashed` do primeiro exemplo. O espaço nas partes brancas é definido pelo `padding`. A posição da linha foi definida no `top`.